# Three.js camera tilt up or down and keep horizon level

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js

camera.rotate.y pans left or right in a predictable manner.

camera.rotate.x looks up or down predictably when camera.rotate.y is at 180 degrees.

but when I change the value of camera.rotate.y to some new value, and then I change the value of camera.rotate.x, the horizon rotates.

I've looked for an algorithm to adjust for horizon rotation after camera.rotate.x is changed, but haven't found it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In three.js, an object's orientation can be specified by its Euler rotation vector `object.rotation`. The three components of the rotation vector represent the rotation in radians around the object's internal x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis respectively.

The order in which the rotations are performed is specified by `object.rotation.order`. The default order is "XYZ" -- rotation around the x-axis occurs first, then the y-axis, then the z-axis.

Rotations are performed with respect to the object's *internal* coordinate system -- not the world coordinate system. This is important. So, for example, after the x-rotation occurs, the object's y- and z- axes will generally no longer be aligned with the world axes. Rotations specified in this way are not unique.

So, for example, if in code you specify,

```
camera.rotation.y = y_radians;  // Y first
camera.rotation.x = x_radians;  // X second
camera.rotation.z = 0;
```

the rotations are applied in the object's `rotation.order`, not in the order you specified them.

In your case, you may find it more intuitive to set `rotation.order` to "YXZ", which is equivalent to "heading, pitch, and roll".

For more information about Euler angles, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). Three.js follows the Tait–Bryan convention, as explained in the article.

three.js r.61

Comment: Your comment worked. At camera object initialization, I added the following line of code, `camera.eulerOrder = "YXZ";`

Comment: Now it is `camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';`

Comment: Don't you mean "yaw, pitch and roll" ? :)

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for the same info for few days now, the trick is: use regular rotateX to look up/down, but use `rotateOnWorldAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), angle)` for horiz turn (https://discourse.threejs.org/t/vertical-camera-rotation/15334).

Comment: Avoid instantiating a new `THREE.Vector3` unnecessarily. Create one and reuse it.