# Rotate a Mesh along x y z axis in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three.js and I can't figure out how to rotate the mesh along x y z axis in correct sequence.

I have this:

```
mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 4;
mesh.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 4;
```

The result is rotated along z followed by a rotation along x. However I want a rotation along x first then a rotation along z. How can I accomplish this in Three.js?

Comment: Everthing you need to know is provided in the answer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by reversing the order of rotation with mesh.rotation.order = "ZYX"