# How do I rotate the direction of the Z axis?

Tags: three.js, camera, rotation

I recently started using Three.js to work on my game project, but I can´t get my camera to walk around.

The problem is: I can rotate the camera on the X axis, but when it goes towards the Z axis, it goes always to the same direction, because the Z axis does not change when I rotate the view. Here is my code so far:

```
var circle = Math.PI / 180;

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 15, 3 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x05ff68 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );

    var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material );
    scene.add(sphere);

    sphere.position.set(-20,0,0);

    camera.position.z = 30;
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 10;

    camera.rotation.y = 0 * circle;
    camera.rotation.x = 0 * circle;

    cube.position.set(20,0,0)

    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

    render();

    function checkKey(e) {

        e = e || window.event;

        if (e.keyCode == '87') {
            camera.position.y -= 2;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '83') {
            camera.position.y += 2;
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == '65') {
            camera.rotation.y += 2 * circle;
        }
         else if (e.keyCode == '68') {
            camera.rotation.y -= 2 * circle;
        };

    }
```

I need to know how to change the direction of Z.

[image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-7oNrCaq35yU/VKhJ71EowUI/AAAAAAAAAA0/XwrWI0tn3Zo/w769-h577-no/camera1.png]

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5L_cAUIkMgQ/VKhKMNe6seI/AAAAAAAAABI/xk_kLqpM6_A/w769-h577-no/camera2.png]

[image: https:lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZNnvGOUkd-g/VKhKSs4-eaI/AAAAAAAAABY/P2VnnsI7Jbg/w769-h577-no/camera3.png]

[image: https:lh6.googleusercontent.com/-lNnhq2CqFxE/VKhKTT32HWI/AAAAAAAAABg/IJoCxjYq57U/w769-h577-no/camera4.png]

[image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-OWus1HMs8gg/VKhKUAnZGBI/AAAAAAAAABo/VArAhWSpEsQ/w769-h577-no/camera5.png]

Comment: You need to have a conceptual understanding of how rotations work in three.js. Start by studying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092.

Comment: @WestLangley sincce I cannot yet post images, can you give me an email adress so I can send you some images that show what I am trying to express in words on this topic?

Comment: Put the URLs for any images in the question.  State that you were unable to include them due to reputation limitations. Someone will come along and edit the post to put them in.

Comment: Edited to add the images.