# three.js mesh tilt instead of rotate

Tags: javascript, three.js, tilt

I just learned about the THREE.js and am fascinated with it's abilities.  I am no where advanced enough to write my own code so I have been browsing around trying to find an example to do exactly what I need or close to but so far with no avail :(

What I am working with is some code that moves an object by using the mouse.  The X axis works prefectly but the Y axis rotates around the object instead of tilts it left and right.

My current code :

```js
var container, stats;

var camera, scene, renderer;

var group, text, plane;

var targetRotationX = 0;
var targetRotationOnMouseDownX = 0;

var targetRotationY = 0;
var targetRotationOnMouseDownY = 0;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

var mouseY = 0;
var mouseYOnMouseDown = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

var finalRotationY
var center

init();
animate();

function init() {



        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 1000;
        camera.eulerOrder = "YXZ"

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // lights

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
        light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
        scene.add( light );

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
        light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
        scene.add( light );

        light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
        scene.add( light );


  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1400, 100, 700, 10, 10, 10);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xfffff, wireframe: true});
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  //cube.position.set( center.x, center.y, center.z );
  //cube.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( -center.x, -center.y, -center.z ) );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  group = new THREE.Object3D();
  group.add(cube)
  scene.add(group);


        // renderer

        //stats = new Stats();
        //stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        //stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
        //container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

        //

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        //for debuging stats
        interval = setInterval( debugInfo, 50 );

}

function modelLoadedCallback(geometry) {

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        group.add(mesh);
        scene.add( group );

}

function onWindowResize() {

        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

//

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

        mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotationOnMouseDownX = targetRotationX;

        mouseYOnMouseDown = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
        targetRotationOnMouseDownY = targetRotationY;

}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

        mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
        mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;


        targetRotationY = targetRotationOnMouseDownY + (mouseY - mouseYOnMouseDown) * 0.02;
        targetRotationX = targetRotationOnMouseDownX + (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.02;



}

function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

}

function onDocumentMouseOut( event ) {

        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

}

function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

        if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationOnMouseDownX = targetRotationX;

                mouseYOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
                targetRotationOnMouseDownY = targetRotationY;



        }

}

function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

        if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationX = targetRotationOnMouseDownX + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;

                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;
                targetRotationY = targetRotationOnMouseDownY + (mouseY - mouseYOnMouseDown) * 0.05;

        }

}

//

function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        render();
        //stats.update();

}

function render() {


     //horizontal rotation
     group.rotation.y += ( targetRotationX - group.rotation.y ) * 0.1;


     finalRotationY = (targetRotationY - group.rotation.x);


    if (group.rotation.x <= 1 && group.rotation.x >= -1) {

        group.rotation.x += finalRotationY * 0.1;
    }
    if (group.rotation.x > 1) {

        group.rotation.x = 1
    }
    else if (group.rotation.x < -1) {

        group.rotation.x = -1
    }



        renderer.render( scene, camera );

}


function debugInfo()
{
    //$('#debug').html("mouseX : " + mouseX + "   mouseY : " + mouseY + "</br>")

}
```

```css
<style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

What I was hoping to do is when the mouse is clicked and moving either left or right, the box will tilt towards the mouse and keep the same "X" rotation unless the mouse is moving up or down as well.  Right now, the camera seems to rotate around the object instead of tilt in the corresponding direction.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you tried, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what is asked for so i'll just leave a comment instead of an answer. I think what you want to do is rotate around the Z axis instead of the Y-axis when the mouse is moved left or right...?

Comment: Make sure you understand [how rotations work in three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092).

Comment: To better explain, I am doing this for a Solar panel control panel.  I have 10 solar panels on a tilt system.  The panels are on a long frame that is mounted centered on 3 poles.  That is the axis I am trying to replicate on this 3D model.  Each panel also tilts on the frame the as the code above does when you click and move the mouse up or down.

Comment: The end result will be my solar panel tracking software that communicates with my web server will send the current angle of the panels on the X and Y axis and I want to display it on the screen to see how the panels are setting even if I am hundreds of miles away :)  I am currently using the HTML canvas method now but the 3D way is so much cooler!

Answer (score 0):

micnil was right and I had to change the rotation order to "ZYX".  Now off to learning how to join my 2 scripts together.