# ThreeJS X Rotation behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I'm making a ThreeJS Demo, and I'm currently using the arrow keys to rotate the camera. At first things seem to work out ok. I can successfully rotate up and down, and left and right. However, when I turn to the left, and then try to rotate up or down, it rotates up and down, but NOT relative to my current position - it acts as if I hadn't rotated left at all.

Here's my current render code:

```
function render() {
plane.rotation.y += 0.005;
cube.rotation.z += 0.01;
 cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
if(window.isLeftDown){
    camera.rotation.y += 0.01;
}
if(window.isRightDown){
    camera.rotation.y -= 0.01;
}
if(window.isUpDown){
    camera.rotation.x -= 0.01;
}
if(window.isDownDown){
    camera.rotation.x += 0.01;
}
requestAnimationFrame( render );
renderer.render( scene, camera2, renderTarget, true);
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092

Comment: Hmm. That's close - I set the camera.rotation.order to "YZX", however now the left and right rotation is messed up instead of the up and down rotation. @WestLangley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092) for an explanation of how rotations work in three.js.

That post suggests changing the Euler order to `YXZ`.

```
camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
```

In your case, however, you may find using the `rotateX()`/`rotateY()` methods preferable. Instead of changing the Euler order, use this pattern:

```
if( window.isLeftDown ){

   camera.rotateY( 0.01 ); // or rotateX( +/- 0.01 )

}
```

The solution you choose depends on the behavior you prefer.

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks! The rotateX, rotateY and rotateZ methods worked perfectly for this situation.