# 3D camera X axis rotation

Tags: camera, three.js

I have litteraly no clue how to explain this problem, since it is is self explanitory if you look at the following video's I made.

No Angle - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_GtaXWpP9c&feature=youtu.be

Angle -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoaZMccGYGo&feature=youtu.be

As you can see in the No Angle version you can rotate the Y axis perfectly normal, but when you control the X axis (as seen in the 'Angle' video) you rotate in a weird way, which makes sense. I want, as you may have guessed, that the X axis stays the same whilst the Y axis keeps moving left to right, I dont want the Y axis to dip from positive to negative.

I hope this makes sense and hopefully there is a good explanation for it, i'm probably missing a  website which has all the formulas, but im not sure what the 'problem' is called.

Some code of my rotation script:

```js
var pressed = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
function update() {
    $('#w').html(pressed);
}
setInterval(update, 100);
$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which == 87) {
        pressed[0] = 1;
    }
    if(evt.which == 68) {
        pressed[1] = 1;
    }
    if(evt.which == 65) {
        pressed[2] = 1;
    }
    if(evt.which == 83) {
        pressed[3] = 1;
    }
    if(evt.which == 39) {
        pressed[4] = 1;
    }
    if(evt.which == 37) {
        pressed[5] = 1;
    }
    if(evt.which == 38) {
        pressed[6] = 1;
    }
    if(evt.which == 40) {
        pressed[7] = 1;
    }
    //console.log(evt.which);
});
$(document).keyup(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which == 87) {
        pressed[0] = 0;
    }
    if(evt.which == 68) {
        pressed[1] = 0;
    }
    if(evt.which == 65) {
        pressed[2] = 0;
    }
    if(evt.which == 83) {
        pressed[3] = 0;
    }
    if(evt.which == 39) {
        pressed[4] = 0;
    }
    if(evt.which == 37) {
        pressed[5] = 0;
    }
    if(evt.which == 38) {
        pressed[6] = 0;
    }
    if(evt.which == 40) {
        pressed[7] = 0;
    }
});
function check_pressed() {
    if(pressed[0] == 1){
        camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 0.1;
    }
    if(pressed[1] == 1){
        camera.position.x = camera.position.x + 0.1;
    }
    if(pressed[2] == 1){
        camera.position.x = camera.position.x - 0.1;
    }
    if(pressed[3] == 1){
        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.1;
    }
    if(pressed[4] == 1){
        if(camera.rotation.y <= Math.PI * -2) {
            camera.rotation.y = 0;
        } else {
            camera.rotation.y -= 0.03;
        }
    }
    if(pressed[5] == 1){
        if(camera.rotation.y >= Math.PI * 2) {
            camera.rotation.y = 0;
        } else {
            camera.rotation.y += 0.03;
        }
    }
    if(pressed[6] == 1){
        if(camera.rotation.x >= 0.5) {
            camera.rotation.x = 0.5;
        } else {
            camera.rotation.x += 0.01;
        }
    }
    if(pressed[7] == 1){
        if(camera.rotation.x <= 0) {
            camera.rotation.x = 0;
        } else {
            camera.rotation.x -= 0.01;
        }
    }

}
setInterval(check_pressed, 20);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My first three.js app</title>
  <style>
   body { margin: 0; }
   canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/movement.js"></script>
  <script>
   var cubes = [];
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            //var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

   var scene = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

   var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x63AEDB } );
    } else {
                    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    }
                cubes[i] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( cubes[i] );
            }
            cubes[1].position.x = -2;
            cubes[1].position.z = 2;
            cubes[2].position.x = 2;
            cubes[2].position.z = 2;
            cubes[3].position.z = 4;
   camera.position.z = 2;
   camera.rotation.y = 0;
   //console.log(camera.rotation.x);
   var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );

    //cubes[1].rotation.x += 0.00;
    //cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
   };
   render();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you rotating your camera? Do you have some code to show?

Comment: There you go, there is the full code. I made a small system where it checks if you are holding a button or not, thats why there is so much code for such a small system... I also made some restrictions to how far up you can go etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157515/threejs-x-rotation-behaving-unexpectedly/32158005#32158005. Experiment until you understand how Euler angles work in three.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivots are not required. The simple solution to your issue is to set

```
camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ'; // the default is 'XYZ'
```

Then, the camera rotations will behave as you expect.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092) for more information.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07g07uLa/1/

Note in the fiddle, there are no pivots, and there is no need to add the camera to the scene.

three.js r.84

Comment: Also thank you, I gave you the best answer (no offense to the other guy).

Comment: I didn't know about that `order` property for Euler angles, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

You're rotating your camera **in its own coordinate system**.

When `camera.rotation.x` (or `z`) is not 0, the *y* axis is transformed and not pointing upwards anymore. That explains why the rotation behaves weirdly.

[image: Coordinate system of the camera modified]

If you want your *y* axis to be in the coordinate system of the world, you can add a `THREE.Object3D` acting as a *pivot point* as a parent of your `camera`.

[image: Camera rotation in world coordinates through a pivot]

```
var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(pivot);
pivot.add(camera);
```

Now, the `rotation.y` of your camera is controlled by the `pivot` :

```
pivot.rotation.y += 0.03;
```

...And so is the `position` :

```
pivot.position.z = 2.0;
```

I updated your code on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07g07uLa/).

Comment: Thanks, good explanation and you took the time for a fix aswell which is awesome! I'll be sure to do this fix on my own so I can learn from it :D

Comment: Thanks, but you should go for the solution prosposed by [WestLangley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1461008/westlangley) ;)

Comment: Yep thanks anyway for the help and taking the time to edit the code and making the pictures etc. !

Comment: Don't worry it's a pleasure