# Three.js Rotating camera pitch not working?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm very new to three.js and so sorry if this is a stupid question.

The issue is that I have a camera and I want to rotate it with the arrow keys. The left and right (yaw) rotation seems to work as excepted, however when the angle is not at 0 the  camera seems to rotate incorrectly up and down (pitch). I have seen this issue been addressed and the way they fixed was in how three.js handles their euler angles as they have a specific order. (YXZ) However I've tried:

```
camera.rotation.y = AngleY;
camera.rotation.x = AngleX;
camera.rotation.z = AngleZ;
```

I have also tried using vectors and camera.target.lookAt, but since camera.target has been removed I am not sure how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set `camera.rotation.order = "YXZ";`.

Comment: Thanks West Langley.  It works now. Originally I thought that three.js sets the order by default :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera's rotation will have meaning in terms of "heading", "pitch", and "roll" if you set:

```
camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ'; // the default is 'XYZ'
```

For more information, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518092/1461008).

three.js r.83