# Gimbal lock at y axis 90 degrees

Tags: three.js

I found a problem with rotations.
Using the transform controls helper, if I rotate a mesh on the Y axis, when I reach 90 degrees everything is flipped by -180 degrees.

I think this is due to the software avoiding gimbal lock, how to avoid it?
**That is, I would like the x- and z-angles to remain 0 degrees in the display.**

I tried even on the threejs editor (https://threejs.org/editor/) and it occurs even there.
Please help me :)!

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is has nothing to do with Gimbal lock.

three.js is quaternion-based. An equivalent Euler angle representation is provided for convenience.

Euler angles are not unique; there are many Euler angles that represent the same orientation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518092/1461008) for info on how Euler angles work in three.js.

If you want to rotate an object on the y-axis only, and have `object.rotation.y` be continuous, you can do so by changing the rotation order like so:

```
object.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
```

three.js r.87

Comment: Ok, understood, thank you very much! I will switch everything considering angles from quaternions instead from meshes rotation euler.
Thank you again :)!