# Problem with threejs object rotation values

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Have problem with rotation values of object,

i am using transform controls to enable rotation control.

i have observed that object is rotated with values of (x:0, y:1.57, z:0 )
and the same object which rotated with values of ( x:1.12, y:1.57, z:-1.12 ) are looking same,

Can someone help me understand or solve this issue

Comment: And verified same with babylon.js but it gives different result for the same values

Comment: 3D rotations are tricky. The problem here is that the object is rotated in order, first by x, then y, then z, in world space. And the Y-rotation by 1.57 or ~90° in between will cause the `z: -1.12` to almost exactly undo the previous `x: 1.12` rotation (because you've rotated the object's x axis onto the world's z axis).

Comment: "Euler angles are not unique" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172742/gimbal-lock-at-y-axis-90-degrees