# Rotate towards the direction in 3D using Three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, three.js, rotation

I have a simple cone flying in 3D space (with a continuous curl noise kind of movement and the camera following it):

[image]

I am trying to understand what is the right way to rotate the cone according to its direction. I got it working with the following (assuming `velocity` is a `Vector3`):

```
cone.rotation.y = Math.atan2(-velocity.z, velocity.x)
cone.rotation.z = Math.asin(velocity.y / velocity.length())
```

I copied this from a three.js example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html

This works, but sometimes the cone makes a sudden movement without any apparent reason (anything to do with the dreaded "gimbal lock" maybe?).

Could someone explain what are the principles of 3D rotation here and what is the best or most efficient way to update the rotation in real time (maybe using matrices)?

Comment: For how `object.rotation` works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it does not offers an explanation on how to use matrices (or `lookAt`) or if using Y and Z rotations is the right way to keep the agent pointing towards its direction