# Three.js Set absolute local rotation

Tags: matrix, three.js, rotation, quaternions

I have a program that rotates a cube based on some serial input. The serial input provides the absolute rotation the cube should be at (such as 20 degrees). I have limits on the cube's rotation such as X from -45 to 45 degrees.

I'm currently storing the current rotation for X,Y,Z, calculating the difference between the current rotation and the new rotation, and then using .rotateX() .rotateY() and .rotateZ() to rotate the cube based on its local position.

```
curX = 0; // Global variable

function updateCubeRotation(newX) {
    // Limit X
    if(newX < 45 && newX > -45) {
        cube.rotateX(THREE.Math.degToRad(newX - curX));
        curX = newX;
    }
}
```

This works great except in one scenario. When I first start my program if the serial data is outside of the soft limits, I can't easily set the cubes rotation to an absolute rotation such as 45 or -45. I could add in a check if the current rotation is not set and its outside of the limits, to set it to the limit value but this seems like a lot of unnecessary code.

I'm curious if there's a way to make SET (not add to) the absolute local rotation for an axis, instead of calculating the difference. This would also allow me to not have to keep track of the last local rotation value for each axis. Something like:

```
// Sets the cubes local rotation to 45, no matter what the current angle is 
cube.setRotateX(45);
```

I'm guessing this is possible with quaterion calculations but I'm unsure of the math that needs to happen for this.

```
.quaternion : Quaternion
Object's local rotation as a Quaternion.
```

I was originally using cube.rotation.x = 45, but this rotates in the world space. Comparing this to Unity, they have the property cube.localRotation.x, which is what I'm trying to emulate.

---

**Update**

I see that the documentation says that .rotation is local but I'm still confused because from what I can tell its rotating via the world coordinates. Whats the difference between .rotateX and .rotation.x?

Logging both rotateX and rotation.x I can see that rotateX changes rotation.x, rotation.y and rotation.z to properly rotate on the local axis. Since more than 1 of the axis's has to change, than that means its relative to the world axis, which conflicts with the documentation?

Here are examples of rotateX and rotation.x:

**rotateX** - Desired rotation, but only takes the difference between last position and new position instead of an absolute value.

```
 console.log(cube.rotation.x)

 x       y       z
 0.1011 -0.6073 -0.5624
-0.0143 -0.5418 -0.6252
-0.1162 -0.4741 -0.6748
-0.2075 -0.4053 -0.7137
-0.2875 -0.3387 -0.7428
-0.3572 -0.2764 -0.7640
-0.4148 -0.2221 -0.7782
-0.4616 -0.1764 -0.7875
-0.4983 -0.1398 -0.7932
-0.5289 -0.1088 -0.7970
```

[image]

**rotation.x** - Undesired rotation

```
 console.log(cube.rotation.x)

 x       y       z
 0.6109 -0.0298 -0.7854
 0.6051 -0.0298 -0.7854
 0.4279 -0.0298 -0.7854
 0.2683 -0.0298 -0.7854
 0.1125 -0.0298 -0.7854
-0.0346 -0.0298 -0.7854
-0.1684 -0.0298 -0.7854
-0.3198 -0.0298 -0.7854
-0.5058 -0.0298 -0.7854
-0.6109 -0.0298 -0.7854
```

[image]

---

```
cube.rotation.x = THREE.Math.degToRad(45);
```

If .rotation was in fact local, wouldn't setting the x to degToRad(45) cause the rotation to be like the first example, but only need to change the x axis?

---

**JS Fiddle Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/jrj2211/m2cwvu0p/20/

Comment: I think you need to understand this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the `cube.rotation.x` property to set an absolute value (instead of a change in value)

```js
// Sets absolute rotation
setRotation(newRot) {
    // Clamps value so it does not exceed +/- 45
    var clampedRot = THREE.Math.clamp(newRot, -45, 45);

    // Assigns new rotation in radians
    cube.rotation.x = THREE.Math.degToRad(clampedRot);
}
```

> I was originally using cube.rotation.x = 45, but this rotates in the world space.

I don't believe this is true. I think the problem is that if you use `cube.rotation.x = 45`, you'll get undesired results because rotation is calculated in *radians*, not degrees. Using literal `45` gives you about 7 full spins, you should be using `THREE.Math.degToRad(45);`

Comment: To me it seems like cube.rotation.x is its world space rotation, even though the docs say its local. I've added an update to my question and maybe you can shed some light on my confusion.

Comment: Ah, your update significantly compounds the original question because you're adding three rotations together, which seems to be causing some [gimbal lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno). This is a very common problem when using Euler rotations, and happens a lot in 3D and game development. You might need to switch to [quaternions](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Quaternion) instead of setting Euler rotations. Can you add your example to a JSFiddle to see if that's the problem?

Comment: I added a JS Fiddle to the end of the post. I do think I need to switch to quaternions as looking at the source code for rotateX(), that uses quaternions. So ideally i'd find a way to to do something similar to rotateX() that can just take an absolute rotation value instead of a velocity.

Comment: The issue I'm now having with rotateX() though is my serial controller can return very large numbers and if I tell it to rotate back to 0,0,0 from say a rotation like 15000,0,0 I think some decimal place precision is lost as the cube will end up being rotated several degrees even though it reports 0 degrees. Being able to force it to a specific angle would be much better.