# Rotation for object3D using accelerometers

Tags: three.js, rotation, accelerometer

I am using MEMs accelerometers to move an avatar using THREE.js library. However I am facing a problem when sensor is rotated around X, Y, and Z at the same time since my avatar does not get the right position. I mean, it does not reflect the position of the MEMs accelerometer. Let me explain this using images. We have the sensor in this initial position. Red Axis is X, Green is Y and Blue is Z:

Initial position

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQSsL.jpg

Now, when sensor is rotate to get this new position, it sends that X = 90, Y = -90, Z = 90 degrees:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/njGBO.jpg

This is sent by the sensor since comparing the object coordinates to world coordinates, effectively X is now where Z was, Z is were Y was and Y is were X was; then all of them are rotated.

The problem I facing is that I don't know how to indicate to my avatar to reach this position.  Using local or world rotations with or without quaternions I get that point using just 2 rotations.  For example, using quaternions I just need to rotate in X and Z -90 degress.

```
    var rotation = new THREE.Quaternion();
    rotation.setFromEuler( new THREE.Euler(x_angle, y_angle, z_angle, 'XYZ') );
    bone.setRotationFromQuaternion(rotation);
```

Reading this post: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136174/im-rotating-an-object-on-two-axes-so-why-does-it-keep-twisting-around-the-thir

I get a closer understanding, but this is done given two angles, and at the end talks about limitations which I reckon are the ones I have.  However, I don't understand the solution he posted for this limitation.

How can achieve this position with the information given by the sensor? There is a way to know which is the redundant axis?

Your help is really appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please share your code that applies the given rotation values from your sensor to the mesh?

Comment: I just did it.  Sorry for my delay, I had a very complicated week. Thanks :)

Comment: @FabioGuarnizo (1) Read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092) and experiment until you understand it. (2) Find and understand the Euler convention used by your MEMS. (3) If you can't do (2), then use trial-an-error by varying `avatar.rotation.order`.