# How to set object matrix? three.js

Tags: three.js

Here's what was learned about the matrix, its OFF.
You have to correct sphere north poles, or live with it.

```js
function hostmat(i) {
  var d = [0, -23,-5,0, 245,5, 95,-27,290,0,0,-27]; d = d[i];
  if (!d) return invhost(i); /// probably closer than nothing
  var r = [-1,0,0], u = NP[i], e = [0,0,1]; u = multv(u,.95);
  u = rotation(dtor(d),[0,1,0],u);
  e = normaliz(crossprod(r,u));
  r = normaliz(crossprod(u,e));
  return new THREE.Matrix4().set(r[0],r[1],r[2],0,u[0],u[1],u[2],0,e[0],e[1],e[2],0,0,0,0,1);
}
/// still OFF - 5 degress
function invhost(i) {
  var r = [-1,0,0], u = NP[i], e = [0,0,1]; u = multv(u,1.05);
  e = normaliz(crossprod(r,u));
  r = normaliz(crossprod(u,e));
  var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().set(r[0],r[1],r[2],0,u[0],u[1],u[2],0,e[0],e[1],e[2],0,0,0,0,1);
return matrix.getInverse(matrix);
}
```

New Project page: http://innerbeing.epizy.com/code/codewgl.html

Comment: Did you try the `makeTranslation` function on the matrix? That should move (translate) the matrix in a specific X, y, z direction

Comment: @greenthings (1) Your question is too fragmented to be understood. (2) In three.js, we do not "rotate a matrix"; we "rotate an object". (3) Learn how Euler angles work in three.js. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518092/1461008. (4) Try setting `planet.rotation.eulerOrder = "XZY"`, then `planet.rotation.y += 0.1` should do what you expect. (5) But a better approach is to just do `planet.rotateY( 0.01 )`.

Comment: Here's what you get when you point moon matrix at Earth and use orbit up, looks right now. http://innerbeing.epizy.com/code/moonwebglmat.jpg