# Threejs Rotate around sphere normal to surface with heading

Tags: three.js, rotation

I have a scene where the user can rotate an object around the surface of the sphere, keeping its local Z axis normal to the surface. Heres a JS fiddle, with sliders at the top to rotate around the sphere.

https://jsfiddle.net/dftroy58/14/

This works fine, but now I want to be able to apply a heading to the object, essentially rotating it along its Z axis. At 0 degree heading, the Y axis should point up towards the north pole of the sphere.

I tried to set therotation.z of the object which works when the latitude is 0 degrees, but moving around the sphere, it then rotates where X becomes up at 90 degrees, -Y at 180 and -X at 270.

```
marker.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(Number.parseFloat(heading.value, 10));
```

With that line commented out, the Y axis always points up. How do I get it so I can set the local Z rotation such that it points to the north pole at 0 degrees, but is rotatable by the user?

I could solve this by instead of rotating the marker, change it to axesHelper.rotation.z. This ends up working, but I'd like to remove the axes helper and want to just understand these kind of transformations more.

```
// Works but I want to avoid this
axesHelper.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(Number.parseFloat(heading.value, 10));
```

How would I, without nesting another object, calculate the correct the Z rotation to keep the heading the same as you change latitude?

Comment: Try `marker.rotateZ( THREE.Math.degToRad( Number.parseFloat( - heading.value, 10 ) ) );`

Comment: Wow so simple but it works... would you like to make it an answer so I can mark it as correct? If you could also clear this up for me: I thought rotateZ wasn't an absolute value so you'd need to pass it a delta. Such as passing it 10 degrees would cause it to rotate 10 degrees from its current position, not from 0. I take it that is wrong and it is absolute?

Comment: I'm oblivious, I didnt see the negative sign. That really is a delta.

Comment: 1. I think you need to understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518092/1461008). 2. Also avoid the poles. 3. You can answer your own question, as I already have too many answers to maintain. ;-)