# three js object rotating y rotate z instead

Tags: three.js, rotation, euler-angles

I really can't understand why this is happening, but let me start from the beginning:

I have this finger texture on a plane, and on idle rotation the finger is pointing to the **Y+**.

[image]

I want it to point to **X+** so here is what I did:

1- I first make the finger point to **Z+** by adding -90 for the x-axis.

[image]

Exactly as I expected!

2- the issue is, I set y to 90 and expected it to rotate on Y axis, but instead it rotates on the Z-axis, this is what I got:

[image]

it is still pointing to **Z+**, changing the y rotation didn't work as expected!

What I am doing wrong here? how to make it point to Z+?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Errors

- The **Plane** Object3D is the child of a **PlaneHolder** Object3D which is rotated, so when you rotate **Plane**, it is only rotating in the local space of its parent, so it will act weird. use `Plane.rotateOnWorldAxis(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), THREE.Math.degToRad(90));` to rotate plane on world axis.
- in the first image you provided, the y-axis **blue** is pointing to the opposite direction, however in the 2nd/3rd images it is in the proper direction.
- in the first image you provided, the x-axis **red** the tip arrow is pointing to the opposite direction, and if you rotate 90deg on x-axis it should be pointing to Z+ but it is pointing to Z-, so even the 2nd image is wrong

### Tip

The Three.js **Axis-Helper** has 3 colors (**red**: x-axis, **green**: y-axis, **blue**: z-axis), and the default options are => red pointing to the right, green pointing upwards, and blue pointing to the camera (if camera is added on V3(0,0,5) and looking at V3(0,0,0) which has the axis-helper)