# Force camera to be parallel to ground

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, rendering, quaternions

I want my fly camera to always be parallel to the ground.
In other words I strictly want my camera's right vector to be always (1,0,0).

I created a custom Camera Controller in three.js to simulate some custom camera movements and pointerlock behaviour.

Here, is the main rotation code in update method.

```
this.tmpQuaternion: THREE.Quaternion;
this.camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
...
this.tmpQuaternion
 .set(
   -this.verticalRotationSpeed * this.mouseMovement.movementY,
   -this.horizontalRotationSpeed * this.mouseMovement.movementX,
   0,
   1
 )
 .normalize();
this.camera.quaternion.multiply(this.tmpQuaternion);
```

Here, `verticalRotationSpeed` and `horizontalRotationSpeed` are just positive constants, and `mouseMovement.movementX` and `mouseMovement.movementY` are just the accumulated mouse movement values after the last rendered frame.

Now, when I move my mouse on both the X and Y axis simultaneouly or in other others diagonally, the camera rolls a bit on the z axis, which I dont want at all.

Can, you kindly explain me the cause behind this behaviour, or at least provide a corrected version of my code, which would keep the camera's right vector to be always facing (1,0,0).

Remark: I want a threejs specific answer. Or in other words what can be achieved with the [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) library.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Alternatively, set heading and pitch, with roll set to zero. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518092/1461008.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you. This solved my problem. I had stumbled upon this question earlier, but didn't expect it work on my case. Actually, the second answer was what I needed to solve it. And your explaination helped my understand this issue a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WestLangley comment solved my problem.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67856474/10638802

Posting a fresh answer for future viewers.

```
this.upVector: THREE.Vector3 = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
this.camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
...
    this.camera.rotateX(
      -this.verticalRotationSpeed * this.mouseMovement.movementY
    );

    this.camera.rotateOnWorldAxis(
      upVector,
      -this.horizontalRotationSpeed * this.mouseMovement.movementX
    );
```

So, for rotation around the x-axis we rotate around the object's own x-axis using rotateX().

But, to maintain the camera horizontal parallel to the ground, we rotate the camera around the world up(+Y) axis, using rotateOnWorldAxis().

If, we had rotated the camera vertically around the object's own up(+y) axis, we would end up with unnecessary rotations on the z and x axis too, as the object's coordinate system might not align with the world coordinate system (The final scene is rendered around the world coordinate system).

Rotating the camera arount the world vertical(y+) axis ensures that the camera right vector is also parallel to the ground, or in other words the camera stays parallel to the ground while rotating vertically.

Comment: Avoid instantiating a new `THREE.Vector3` every time the mouse moves. Create one and reuse it.

Comment: @WestLangley ok sure.